# How would binding soldiers to war against their will, mock a legal system?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-law

[Source](http://strategicstudiesinstitute.army.mil/pubs/parameters/Articles/1995/christop.htm): *Unjust War ...*, by PAUL CHRISTOPHER, from *Parameters* Autumn 1995, pp 4-8.

> Moreover, it is profoundly arrogant for officers to take the view, as some do, that after the national debate takes place, and after the President and Congress have decided to act, then the officer should have the latitude to follow his or her own conscience, either acceding to or declining to follow the orders of the President. And of course, if such an individual assessment is to be morally permissible for officers, then it must be morally permissible for soldiers of all ranks. Accepting this position inevitably leads to one of two unsatisfactory conclusions. ... The other option is to acknowledge that requiring soldiers to go to war against their will is immoral, but to make such a political decision legally binding on them anyway. ..., and **the second one [alternative] would make a mockery of our legal system**.

Would someone please explain the bolded last sentence? How  and why would this '**make a mockery ...**' ?

Footnote: [This comment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/4894/user4894) helpfully introduced me to this source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make a mockery of the legal system by legally binding things admitted to be immoral.

While I believe what's moral isn't always lawful (and vice versa) there is enough of a connection between law and morality that to blatantly push this dichotomy can raise serious questions about the law.

How would you feel if an authority admitted that the law forced you to do something which that same authority agreed was highly immoral?  It becomes very hard to respect a legal system in which such things take place.